# html not rendered in ng-template angular

Tags: angularjs, json, laravel, recursion, angularjs-ng-include

I have some jsons data such as below, when I tried to print them recursively with ng-include and ng-template (as shown below), the ng-include's inside html codes doesnot rendered and it is blank. 
and other problem is that in printing ng-include , it just print 1 level of recursion and it doesn't keeping on printing.

so what's wrong?

Json data:

```
[{"name":"default","path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>","subdir":[{"name":"css","path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>>default","subdir":[{"name":"images","path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>>default>css","subdir":[]},{"name":"style.css","path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>>default>css"}]},{"name":"index.blade.php","path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>>default"},{"name":"information.json","path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>>default"},{"name":"screen.jpg","path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>>default"}]}]
```

Html code:

```
<div class="theme-files-list ltr" ng-init="loadDir('{{ $theme }}')">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="directoryTree">
      <div class="tree-item">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o maroon"></i>
        <a href="<% '/admin/setting/template/edit/{{ $theme }}/'+item.name %>">
          <% item.name %>
        </a>
      </div>
      <ul ng-if="item.subdir">
          <li ng-repeat="item in item.subdir" ng-include="'directoryTree'"></li>
      </ul>
    </script>
    <ul class="noselect">
        <li>
          <div class="tree-item bg-aqua">
            <i class="fa fa-paint-brush blue"></i>
            {{ ucfirst($theme) }}
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in themeDir" ng-include="'directoryTree'"></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> **important**: I use laravel and for blade system print, I have replaced angular print symbols {{ }} with <% %>

Comment: you can use Laravel `@{{ }} ` that doesn't require you to change the angular `{{ }} ` syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use different code. Your json represent a tree of folder but in the angular app, you're only iterating on the first level and in the first level you have only 1 item with subdir.

If you format correctly your json response you can easily understand this.

```
[
  {
    "name":"default",
    "path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>",
    "subdir":
        [
        {
          ******** You're targeting this element below **********
          "name":"css",
          "path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>>default",
          "subdir":
                    [
                     {
                        "name":"images",
                        "path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>>default>css",
                        "subdir":[]
                      },
                      {
                         "name":"style.css",
                         "path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>>default>css"
                      }
                     ]
        },
        {
         ******** This doesn't has subdir **********
          "name":"index.blade.php",
          "path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>>default"
        },
        {
         ******** This doesn't has subdir **********             
          "name":"information.json",
          "path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>>default"
        },
        {
         ******** This doesn't has subdir **********
          "name":"screen.jpg",
          "path":">var>www>rapa-v2>themes>>default"
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

So you have to change the json or to change ng-repeat

Comment: i tried to seperate the folders and files with subdir property, so what's your suggestion for json format?

Comment: i have problem yet .